# UITableViewVibrantCell on UITableView

Tags: tableview, swift4, side-menu, uivibrancyeffect

I would like to know if it was possible to use UITableViewVibrantCell on a UITableView (not controller). I can't figure out how to do it.

I'm doing :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath) as! UITableViewVibrantCell

        cell.blurEffectStyle = SideMenuManager.default.menuBlurEffectStyle

        return cell
    }
```

My UIViewController inherit from UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: May i Know what is your problem??

Comment: My problem is that I'm using the SideMenu library, and I can't figure out how to apply the UITableViewVibrantCell on an UITableView, and not an UITableViewController. The developer told me it was possible but that I should ask on StackOverflow, so here I am :)

Comment: Please share your library link. So that I can create a demo project.

Comment: Here it is : https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu